# No wireless ubuntu13.10

Tags: wireless, broadcom, 13.10

Installed ubuntu 13.10 yesterday no internet connection.12.10 ok and dongle ok,13.4 no dongle, nothing now. Compac mini 110c, broadcom 4313 (AR8132 Q.Atheros.) Only have ubuntu on notebook.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ubuntu disables some 3rd party sources, which might include some network drivers.

From the Settings Manager option in menu open "Software & Updates". Try to check "Software restricted by copyright" and "Proprietary drivers"

Answer (score 0):

There is actually more than one broadcom 4313 adapter.  Open the terminal and enter:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

The number following "14e4:" in the output is the actual adapter.  Post that.

My netbook has a broadcom 4313 which is actually 14e4:4727 (rev 01).  It's a very persnickety adapter, but it worked better for me in 13.04 than 12.04 and I think it runs better so far in 13.10.  But that may not be your exact adapter ...